# How to resolve 'Fatal error: out of memory' issue on a staging site?

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I have a website and a staging website running on the same server. I created the staging site by duplicating the website, setting up a new database, and putting it on a subdomain. Both run Wordpress, latest version. Server is Ubuntu 18.04.

Both sites function properly, however the staging site gets constant `Fatal error: Out of memory` errors on the front-end and back-end. My server isn't going above 40-45% CPU usage, and I'm not doing anything particularly intensive (just tweaking plugins, changing bits of code, etc).

So far I have tried:

- Increasing memory limit via wp-config (2048m)
- Activating wp_debug, whose log file is profoundly un-useful

Log file:

```
[05-Oct-2018 12:14:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 
20971520) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/STAGINGURL/public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge/includes/shortcodes/shortcode-elements/portfolio-list.php on line 771
[05-Oct-2018 12:14:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 20971520) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/STAGINGURL/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-logger.php on line 1
[05-Oct-2018 12:14:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 29360128) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/STAGINGURL/public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge/includes/shortcodes/shortcode-elements/portfolio-list.php on line 771
[05-Oct-2018 12:14:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 29360128) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /var/www/html/STAGINGURL/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-logger.php on line 1
```

The file named in the error seems to vary each time, including on refresh.

Any help appreciated. As I say, the main site is working fine.

Comment: there's a memory leak in that plugin - disable and see if it works (it will)

Comment: As I say, the file named in the error varies each time. The 4 entries there were the contents of my debug file when I asked the question, but now there are over 500 entries. All manner of plugins are included, and it's not just plugins either: `/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php`, `/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php`, `public_html/wp-content/themes/bridge/header.php` and `/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php` are just a small sample of the others.

Comment: if you disable all plugins, wp should work, enable one by one to find your leak

Comment: OK thank you. If this is the cause and I isolate the plugin causing the leak, will reinstalling resolve it? The site needs all of the plugins it has to function correctly.

Comment: Can't honestly say - I'm not familiar with the plugin

Comment: @ChrisL If there's a memory leak in one of your plugins, reinstalling will not usually fix it - it tends to require a fix of the plugin's code.

Comment: I really doubt WooCommerce is the source of the problem then. I changed my memory allocation via php.ini and that seems to have helped, although I'm confused as to why other sites on my VPS weren't (and still aren't) having memory errors.